# Another badge question. Tag badges

Tags: support, badges

I decided to leave the 2 questions I found answers to in here in case others have the same questions.

Four of us have received the bronze badge for 'science-based'.  Great.  However, 3 of us have more than 1 tag that would qualify.  If it was just me, I'd wait a couple more days, but Tim B has a couple that should have been awarded a while ago and so does HDE.

On top of that the Generalist Badge isn't being awarded.  I could see if there is some 'beta' restriction but then why show it at all?  I also looked at Code Review which is in beta and they have awarded 21 of them. I qualify and Tim has qualified for quite a while, he's closing in on getting all 40 top ten.

Also the taxonomist badge has not been awarded for either 'reality-check' or 'space' (this could be someone who created them 'left' and that would make sense).  I check because I like to see who started each tag.

Comment: The three pro tem mods all have one taxonomist badge each - this amuses me for some reason :)

Comment: @TimB ya, I noticed, it means you guys were in tune with what the community would need!  ;)  No problem on the not being able to answer, but I did want the question out there.

Comment: The '100' questions criteria is interesting; I had been wondering the same thing as you. I guess this clears it up.

Comment: [tag:space] (created by Monica Cellio) and [tag:reality-check] (created by Liath) won't have a Taxonomist badge awarded for them, since their creators already have earned it for other tags.

Comment: @JarrodDixon ah, didn't know that was an earn once badge. (and there is no way for me to see who created a tag until a badge is awarded for it.)  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, we've [never exposed who created a tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6822/3) (until a taxonomist badge is awarded) due to gaming concerns.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I understand that, found that answer before.  But once it passes 50 questions there really isn't much reason to hide it anymore is there?

Comment: That's a really good point! We'll discuss this internally.

Comment: I'm surprised that Taxonomist is a one-shot badge when many others are once per occurrence (Nice/Good/Great, Enlightened, Guru, the Announcer family, the Custodian family...).  Not complaining, just surprised.

Comment: @MonicaCellio  I am too, that's why I expected each badge to show who received it after it hit 50

Comment: Sounds like a good idea too - maybe we should make this a feature-request :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bronze badge is only awarded for a tag once that tag has been used on more than 100 separate questions. So far only science-based has enough although several more are getting close.

The generalist badge only counts tags that have been used on 200 questions, it will not be awarded until there are enough questions on enough tags.

The Taxonomist badge is once-only. Once someone has earned the badge for one tag then even if another tag matches the requirements a second badge will not be awarded to that person.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on our badges.

For the generalist badge progress the top 40 tags have at least 20 questions asked each.

---

We have 15 tags with at least 50 questions (resulting in 9 Taxonomist badges)

We have 6 tags > 100 (technology is at 99!) (allowing for 22 Bronze tag badges to have been awarded)

We have 1 tag over 200 with 1 more (reality-check) at 193

Go us! (2/22/2015)

> Update 5/6/2015:***********************************************

We have 31 tags with at least 50 questions (resulting in 15 Taxonomist badges)

We have 11 tags > 100 (allowing for 43 Bronze tag badges and 1 silver to have been awarded)

We have 5 tags over 200 uses.  When 40 tags hit 200 the Generalist badge will start being awarded. (next update when 40 tags have 50 each)

> Update 7/26/2015 *******************************************

We have 40 tags with at least 50 questions (resulting in 19 Taxonomist badges)

We have 16 tags > 100 (+ 1 @99!) (allowing for 63 Bronze tag badges and 1 silver to have been awarded)

We have 7 tags over 200 uses.  When 40 tags hit 200 the Generalist badge will start being awarded. (next update when 40 tags have 75 each)

> Update 11/17/2015 *************************************************

We have 58 tags with at least 50 questions (resulting in 30 Taxonomist badges) (41 with 75)

We have 26 tags > 100 (+ 1 @99 & 1 @97!) (allowing for 112 Bronze tag badges and 6 silver have been awarded)

We have 11 tags over 200 uses.  When 40 tags hit 200 the Generalist badge will start being awarded. (next update when 40 tags have 100 each)

> Update 03/08/2016 *************************************************

We have 68 tags with at least 50 questions (resulting in 33 Taxonomist badges) (55 with 75)

We have 40 tags >= 100 (allowing for 175 Bronze tag badges and 9 silver have been awarded)

We have 14 tags over 200 uses.  When 40 tags hit 200 the Generalist badge will start being awarded. (next update when 40 tags have 150 each)